# How to use third party components

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I have a simple tasks component, working fine, wanted to add pagination functionality so while added following line

Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined**

even in my app.js vue is being imported like this

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

My Task Component js code

```
Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tasks: {},
            }
        },
        methods: {
            // Our method to GET results from a Laravel endpoint
//            getResults(page = 1) {
//                axios.get('http://laravel.vue.com/tasks?page=' + page)
//                    .then((response) => this.tasks = response.data)
//                    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
//            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component Mounted.')
        },
        created() {
            console.log('Tasks Component Loaded.');
            //console.log(this.tasks);
            axios.get('http://laravel.vue.com/tasks')
            .then((response) => this.tasks = response.data)
//                .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        },
    }
```

Comment: did you install vue.js?

Comment: also include app.js into script tag in your html/blade page

Comment: Yes, my list was working fine with vue, just got the issue while adding pagination in it. I am not sure how to add 3party component in my component. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UwnV68xCSc&list=PL9fcHFJHtFaapJ90VEtHvbqGvDniKkuRT&index=5&t=0s

Comment: I had to add "import Vue from 'vue'" in my component and now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but try this:
In app.js:

```
Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));
```

in your task component js code:

```
<pagination></pagination>
```

Comment: for reference : https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-vue-js-pagination-example-with-demoexample.html